# How to access an "<input type="text" from code behind in ASP NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, code-behind

This is my control

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
        <textarea id="txtDescrizione" name="txtDescrizione" class="materialize-textarea" runat="server" data-length="120" style:"display:none"></textarea>
        <label for="textarea1">Descrizione</label>
</div>
```

I just can't access it from code behind.

When I try

```
txtDescrizione.Visible = false;
```

> It gives me error "txtDescrizione does not exists".

Comment: I am just making a guess here, may be the control is rendered on a conditional basis and when the line in code behind executed, the control may not be redenred on the page.

Comment: But I can access its value with `string proveYou = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["txtDescrizione"]);`

Comment: @sam your text area control is inside any controls like grid, DataList etc.?

Comment: No is not, is only inside that div

Comment: @sam Ok than please check your control is register in designer.cs file if not than removed your control and re add into your page

Comment: @KaushikMaheta Please tag your comment to OP so he will get attention.

Comment: Is not registred!

Comment: @sam Ok than remove your control and re add into your page.

Comment: @KaushikMaheta now that you make me search for it, I see that also the other controls that are **<input type..>** are not registred? What

Comment: @sam do same thing for other controls if you need to access from code behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can change textarea to asp:TextBox

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtDescrizione" TextMode="multiline" Columns="50" Rows="5" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Yeah I know, that would be very simple, but I just wanned to use Materializecss...

Comment: HtmlTextArea txtDescrizione = (HtmlTextArea)(this.FindControl("txtDescrizione"));

Comment: you can add css in asp inputs by using --> cssClass="materialize-textarea"

Comment: Then why I should use **<input type=... >** insed of asp net controls? It would be so simple using them. But still I see a lot of people doing that way. Is there any reason?

Comment: to use html tag <textarea you can access with HtmlTextArea txtDescrizione = (HtmlTextArea)(form1.FindControl("txtDescrizione"));

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247926/asptextbox-vs-input-text-a-php-developer-learning-asp

Comment: form1 is the name of your page , HtmlTextArea txtDescrizione = (HtmlTextArea)(FindControl("txtDescrizione")); see this in Microsoft docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol?view=netframework-4.8